# D3DX11SaveTextureToFile with ID3D11ShaderResourceView

Tags: c++, directx, textures, directx-11, d3dx

I have the `ID3D11ShaderResourceView * textureResView`, and I want to save that texture to file. I guess I should first extract the `ID3D11Texture2D` from it, so I have made a code:

```
ID3D11Resource * res;
ID3D11Texture2D * tex;
textureResView->GetResource(&res);
res->QueryInterface(&tex);
HRESULT result = D3DX11SaveTextureToFile(
    g_pImmediateContext, tex, D3DX11_IFF_PNG, "name.png");
```

Unfortunatelly, that returns `E_FAIL`. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Because E_FAIL came back, there was something wrong in the D3DX11SaveTextureToFile(...) function.
If you use Windows 8 please use an other function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

But I succest try

```
HRESULT result = D3DX11SaveTextureToFile(g_pImmediateContext, tex, D3DX11_IFF_PNG, L"name.png");
```

LPCSTR is a different format to string format, there fore you have to put L infront of the string.

Hope it works